# Name of movie that contains entertainment park with cloned humans where everything is allowed

Tags: story-identification

I saw a movie once where a detective looks for a murderer. There is an entertainment park that has cloned humans (or robots?) and in that park everything is allowed to do with the clones. And I think one of the clones remembers bad things done to her and runs away. Together with her former man?

The movie is not that old. Less then 10 years?

Anyone a suggestion what the title could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be [***Vice***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3480796/) (2015)

> Julian Michaels (Bruce Willis) has designed the ultimate resort: VICE, where anything goes and the customers can play out their wildest fantasies with artificial inhabitants who look, think and feel like humans. When an artificial (Ambyr Childers) becomes self-aware and escapes, she finds herself caught in the crossfire between Julian's mercenaries and a cop (Thomas Jane) who is hell-bent on shutting down Vice, and stopping the violence once and for all.

Comment: Indeed Vice I was looking for! Great.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be Westworld ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westworld.
Westworld is a 1973 American science fiction Western thriller film written and directed by novelist Michael Crichton about amusement park androids that malfunction and begin killing visitors. It stars Yul Brynner as an android in a futuristic Western-themed amusement park, and Richard Benjamin and James Brolin as guests of the park.

The film served as Crichton's first theatrical feature.[3] It was also the first feature film to use digital image processing, to pixellate photography to simulate an android point of view.[4] The film was nominated for Hugo, Nebula, and Saturn awards.

Westworld was succeeded by a sequel, Futureworld (1976), and a short-lived television series, Beyond Westworld (1980). A new television series from HBO, based on the original film, debuted on October 2, 2016.

Comment: No not Westworld. What I saw is much more recent. And not a series.

Comment: Westworld was a movie before it was a series which is why I thought that. Sorry and Good luck finding the movie.